# (Baby Rudin) ch6 Theorem 6.11 (The Riemann-Stieltjes Integral)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, riemann-integration, stieltjes-integral

[image: Ch6 Thm 6.11]
The theorem and the proof above is from Rudin. 
I have a question about the last part of the proof.
For the inequality $\sum_{i \in A}(M_i^*-m^*_i)\Delta\alpha_i+\sum_{i \in B}(M_i^*-m^*_i)\Delta\alpha_i \le \epsilon[\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)]+2K\delta$, I understand that the second term in the right side is made so because $M_i^*-m^*_i\le2K$ for $i\in B$ and $\sum_{i \in B}\Delta\alpha_i<\delta$ as proved in the proof. However, as for the first term in the right side of the inequality, How do we know that $\alpha(b)$ and $-\alpha(a)$ terms are in $\sum_{i \in A} \Delta \alpha_i$? $A$ might not contain $1$ and $n$ so that $\Delta\alpha(x_n)=\alpha(b) - \alpha(x_{n-1})$ and $\Delta\alpha(x_1)=\alpha(x_1)-\alpha(a)$ are not a part of $\sum_{i \in A} \Delta \alpha_i$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is $\alpha$? Is it an increasing function?

Comment: Yes. According to Rudin, $\alpha$ is a monotonically increasing function on $[a, b]$ which is bounded.

Comment: Note that $A \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each $M_i^*-m_i^*\ge0$ and $\Delta\alpha_i\ge0$ as $\alpha_i\ge\alpha_{i-1}$.
Also $M_i^*-m_i^*\le\epsilon$ for $i\in A$. Therefore
$$\sum_{i\in A}(M_i^*-m_i^*)\Delta\alpha_i\le\epsilon\sum_{i\in A}
\Delta\alpha_i.$$
But 
$$\sum_{i\in A}\Delta\alpha_i\le\sum_{i=1}^n\Delta\alpha_i=\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$$
as $\Delta\alpha_i\ge0$ for $i\notin A$. Putting this together
gives the given bound.

Answer (score 2):

Since $M_i - m_i \geqslant 0$ (supremum minus infimum) and $\alpha$ is increasing we have

$$\sum_{i \in A}(M_i-m_i) \Delta \alpha_i \leqslant \sum_{i =1}^n(M_i-m_i) \Delta \alpha_i \leqslant \epsilon[\alpha(b) - \alpha(a)]$$